# Proof in modern algebra. Prove $(n-1)! = -1 \ (\textrm{mod n})$ iff n is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove $(n-1)! = -1 \ (\textrm{mod n})$ iff n is prime

I can understand how the first part of the proof $(n-1)!=-1 \ (\textrm{mod n})$ is true if n is prime simply by testing it out. However, I'm unsure of how to go about proving it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $(n-1)! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot n-1$ and, ignoring $1$, each number on that list has a distinct (why?) multiplicative inverse (why?) on that list except ...

> ... $-1 \cong n-1$ because it is its own inverse.

Comment: Why $n-1$ is the only one with this property? I mean, why the others elements have distinct inverses?

Comment: Suppose $p$ is a prime and $1< k = k^{-1} \pmod{p}$, then $k^2 = mp+1$ for some $m \in \Bbb{Z}$, giving $(k-1)(k+1) = mp$.  Since $0<k-1<k+1<p$ and $p$ is prime, neither $k-1$ not $k+1$ divides $p$, so $(k-1)(k+1) \neq mp$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $n$ is prime then $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a group i.e every element has an inverse. Also, if we know $n$ isprime (assume $>2$) then $n$ is odd. You have;

$$(n-1)! = (n-1)(n-2)(n-3) \cdots 3 \cdot 2$$

The union of all the elements above is $\mathbb{Z}_n$.